# c# - SendPingAsync failing with timeouts all the time

Tags: c#, .net

Here is my code;

```
    private async Task PingAsync(IPAddress target)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($@"pinging {target}..");         

        var tasks = new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 }.Select(async iteration =>
        {
            try
            {
                using (var ping = new Ping())
                {
                    var reply = await ping.SendPingAsync(IpAddress);
                    Console.WriteLine($@"ping result [{iteration}] from {reply.Address} - [{reply.Status}] - {reply.RoundtripTime}");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        });

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
```

and run it using

```
    public async Task Run()
    {
        var Checks = new List<IPAddress>()
        {
            IPAddress.Parse("8.8.8.8"),
            IPAddress.Parse("8.8.4.4"),
            IPAddress.Parse("8.8.1.1"),
        };

        var tasks = Checks.Select(PingAsync);

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
```

So basically in one of my development machines it works all good, but in another development machine with, all checks are failing with timeouts.

**And yes that machine can ping those ip's from command line.**

Any ideas?

Comment: does those machine can normally ping those address? maybe there's a firewall?

Comment: Assuming there is no bug in the BCL, then its environmental

Comment: this sounds like either a firewall or routing configuration thing... neither of which can be fixed through your code here; it *could* also perhaps be related to one machine only supporting IPv6? (the IPv6 address for google DNS is 2001:4860:4860::8888 or 2001:4860:4860::8844)

Comment: actually the machine can just ping using command line.

Answer (score 0):

closing this as it was actually caused by my router.